# return an observable dependent upon a subscription

Tags: angular

Suppose I have a component that calls to a service like so:

```
this.myCustomerService.getCurrentCustomer().subscribe(customer => {
    console.log(customer);
});
```

And in my service, I'd have something like this:

```
getCurrentCustomer(): Observable<any> {
    return this.apiService.get(this.hardCodedPath);
}
```

Where apiService basically just abstracts an http.get and does a little work on the response before returning it.

So, this works perfectly fine. It's pretty easy. But now let's introduce the actual problem.

Suppose I cannot use 'this.hardCodedPath' and I need to depend on something else. Let's revisit that getCurrentCustomer function in my service:

```
getCurrentCustomer(): Observable<any> {
    return this.apiService.get(this.path+'/myEndPoint?sessionID='+this.sessionID);
}
```

The problem is this.sessionID might not yet be defined. Not to worry, I have a session service that can get it for me:

```
this.sessionService.getCurrentSession(this.params).subscribe(response => {
    response = JSON.parse(response);
    this.sessionID = response.sessionId;
}
```

So the nuts and bolts are there, but how do I guarantee when a component calls myCustomerService.getCurrentCustomer() that sessionID will be set? Here's an example that doesn't work:

```
getCurrentCustomer(): Observable<any> {
    this.sessionService.getCurrentSession(this.params).subscribe(response => {
        response = JSON.parse(response);
        this.sessionID = response.sessionId;
        return this.apiService.get(this.path+'/myEndPoint?sessionID='+this.sessionID);
    }
}
```

This won't work because I'm not returning anything! I also cannot simply return the this.sessionService.getCurrentSession... because that will return a subscription, not an observable.

Basically, I need getCurrentCustomer to call to get the sessionID, wait for it, and then call to get the customer and return that observable. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

My first attemp could be

```
getCurrentCustomer(): Observable<any> {
    return this.sessionService.getCurrentSession(this.params).map(response => {
        response = JSON.parse(response);
        return response.sessionId;
    }).flatMap(sessionId => this.apiService.get(this.path+'/myEndPoint?sessionID='+sessionId));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
getCurrentCustomer(): Observable<any> {
  return this.sessionService.getCurrentSession(this.params)
    .map(response => response.json())
    .map(res => res.sessionId)
    .flatMap(sessionId => this.apiService.get(this.path+'/myEndPoint?sessionID='+sessionId));
}
```

using stream for readable, and because response of http request could use method `.json()` do not need `JSON.parse()`

Comment: using stream for readable, and because response of http request could use method `.json()` do not need `JSON.parse`.

Answer (score 0):

Tiep and Victor both posted an answer that works, and the flatmap led me to another version of the same solution:

```
getCurrentCustomer(): Observable<any> {
    return this.sessionService.getCurrentSession(this.params).flatMap(response => {
        response = JSON.parse(response);
        this.sessionID = response.sessionId;
        return this.apiService.get(this.path+'/myEndPoint?sessionID='+this.sessionID);
    });
}
```

Seems basically the same, but it appears we can do the mapping work within flatMap instead of having to chain the flatMap after a map.